# How to render functions onclick submit button in ReactJs?

Tags: javascript, html, json, reactjs

When I click on submit button there should be displayed `hour_slots` and `hour` from the JSON data but when I click on submit button nothing is displayed. I am trying to make use of `showslots()` function to display HTML content below submit button.

datapicker.js :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import data from './data';
import './datepicker.css';

class DatePicker extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
     this.state = {
        counter:0
     };
   }

  increment(){
    if(this.state.counter < 6){
      this.setState(prevState => ({counter: prevState.counter + 1}))
    }
  }

  decrement(){
    if(this.state.counter > 0){
      this.setState(prevState => ({counter: prevState.counter-1}))
   }
  }

  showslots(){
        if(data.available_slots[this.state.counter].date_slots.length === 0){
            return(
                <p>No slots</p>
                )
        }else {
            return(

                    data.available_slots[this.state.counter].data_slots.map(obj =>{

                        <div id="slotinfo">
                            <p>Hour : {obj.hour}</p>
                            <p>Hour slots : {obj.hour_slots[0]}</p>
                            <p>Hour slots : {obj.hour_slots[0]}</p> 
                        </div>
                    })
                )
        }

  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>

        <div id="center">
        <div className="title">
            <p>Pick a Date</p>
        </div>
        <div className="increment">
          <button type="button" className="btn btn-success" id="plus" onClick={this.increment.bind(this)}>+</button>
        </div>
        <div className="display">
          <input type="text" id="date" value={data.available_slots[this.state.counter].date}/>
        </div>
        <div className="decrement">
          <button type="button" className="btn btn-danger" id="minus" onClick={this.decrement.bind(this)}>-</button> 
        </div>
        <div className="status">
          { data.available_slots[this.state.counter].date_slots.length === 0 ? 
          <p>No slots available for today</p> : <p>Slots available for today</p> }
        </div>
        <div className="submit">
          <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary" id="submit" onClick={this.showslots.bind(this)}>Book Slot</button> 
        </div>
      </div>

      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default DatePicker;
```

data.js :

```
const data = {
        "template_type": "slot_picker",
        "selection_color": "#000000",
        "secondary_color": "#808080",
        "title": "Available Slots for Dr. Sumit",
        "available_slots": [
          {
            "date": "Wed, Dec 06",
            "date_slots": [

            ]
          },
          {
            "date": "Thu, Dec 07",
            "date_slots": [

            ]
          },
          {
            "date": "Fri, Dec 08",
            "date_slots": [

            ]
          },
          {
            "date": "Sat, Dec 09",
            "date_slots": [

            ]
          },
          {
            "date": "Today",
            "date_slots": [
              {
                "hour": "8",
                "hour_slots": [
                  {
                    "08:10 AM": "slotId001"
                  },
                  {
                    "08:50 AM": "slotId005"
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "hour": "3",
                "hour_slots": [
                  {
                    "03:00 PM": "slotId005"
                  },
                  {
                    "03:30 PM": "slotId007"
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "date": "Tomorrow",
            "date_slots": [

            ]
          },
          {
            "date": "Wed, Dec 13",
            "date_slots": [
              {
                "hour": "4",
                "hour_slots": [
                  {
                    "04:30 PM": "slotId105"
                  },
                  {
                    "04:50 PM": "slotId106"
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "hour": "5",
                "hour_slots": [
                  {
                    "05:30 PM": "slotId202"
                  },
                  {
                    "05:45 PM": "slotId208"
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      };

 export default data;
```

When I click on submit button it should display slot details but nothing is displayed below submit button as no html is generated dynamically below submit button. see screenshot:
[image]

Comment: You should call the function like below:

```onClick={this.showslots}```

Comment: @salman.zare Made those changes but still does not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found one major error, in the following code

```
                data.available_slots[this.state.counter].data_slots.map(obj =>{

                    <div id="slotinfo">
                        <p>Hour : {obj.hour}</p>
                        <p>Hour slots : {obj.hour_slots[0]}</p>
                        <p>Hour slots : {obj.hour_slots[0]}</p> 
                    </div>
                })
```

Inside the map function, you pass a function which does not returns anything. The correct code, for the same syntax, would be:

```
                data.available_slots[this.state.counter].data_slots.map(obj =>{
                    return (
                      <div id="slotinfo">
                        <p>Hour : {obj.hour}</p>
                        <p>Hour slots : {obj.hour_slots[0]}</p>
                        <p>Hour slots : {obj.hour_slots[0]}</p> 
                      </div>
                    );
                })
```

Please do notice the return statement.

If you would like to not have the return statement, just replace the curly bracket around the function definition with the round brackets.

Comment: @Kapli Why it is not displaying the content when slots are available it only displays no slots

Answer (score 1):

You will need to have an additional state variable `isSubmitted`, initially set to `false` to know whether submit button has been clicked. On clicking submit button, call a function to update the state value of `isSubmitted` to `true`.

```
setSubmitted(){
  this.setState({ isSubmitted:true })
}
```

and change the `onClick` function of the button to `setSubmitted`.

```
<button type="button" className="btn btn-primary" id="submit" onClick={this.setSubmitted.bind(this)}>Book Slot</button>
```

And call `showslots()` wherever it should be displayed (along with the condition so that slots are displayed only after submit button has been clicked), inside the render method like so:

```
{this.state.isSubmitted && this.showslots()}
```

Comment: what changes should I make in my answer check above.

Comment: As KapilDev Neupane noted, you have missed a return statement. Otherwise looks fine. Do you see any errors? Also, in future, please update the question with the code and leave a comment on the answer that you've updated the question, if you need clarifications for an answer. Don't post as a new answer.

Comment: Also noticed a typo - `date_slots`, not `data_slots`.

Comment: I am not getting the HTML content if the slot is avaliable why so ? see snapshot -> https://imgur.com/a/HTxoB For no slots it displays correctly but for slots avaliable it should display the content

Comment: You have missed a return statement inside the `map` in the else part of `showslots()` function. Check KapilDev Neupane's answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/48963722/1421222

Answer (score 0):

datepicker.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import data from './data';
import './datepicker.css';

class DatePicker extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
     this.state = {
        counter:0,
        issubmitted:false
     };
   }

  increment(){
    if(this.state.counter < 6){
      this.setState(prevState => ({counter: prevState.counter + 1}))
    }
  }

  decrement(){
    if(this.state.counter > 0){
      this.setState(prevState => ({counter: prevState.counter-1}))
   }
  }

  formsubmitted(){
    this.setState({
        issubmitted:true
    })
  }

  showslots(){
        if(data.available_slots[this.state.counter].date_slots.length === 0){
            return(
                <p>No slots</p>
                )
        }else {
            return(

                    data.available_slots[this.state.counter].date_slots.map(obj =>{

                        return (
                  <div id="slotinfo">
                    <p>Hour : {obj.hour}</p>
                    <p>Hour slots : {obj.hour_slots[0]}</p>
                    <p>Hour slots : {obj.hour_slots[0]}</p> 
                  </div>
                );
                    })
                )
        }

  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>

        <div id="center">
        <div className="title">
            <p>Pick a Date</p>
        </div>
        <div className="increment">
          <button type="button" className="btn btn-success" id="plus" onClick={this.increment.bind(this)}>+</button>
        </div>
        <div className="display">
          <input type="text" id="date" value={data.available_slots[this.state.counter].date}/>
        </div>
        <div className="decrement">
          <button type="button" className="btn btn-danger" id="minus" onClick={this.decrement.bind(this)}>-</button> 
        </div>
        <div className="status">
          { data.available_slots[this.state.counter].date_slots.length === 0 ? 
          <p>No slots available for today</p> : <p>Slots available for today</p> }
        </div>
        <div className="submit">
          <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary" id="submit" onClick={this.formsubmitted.bind(this)}>Book Slot</button> 
        </div>
      </div>

      <div>
        {this.state.issubmitted ? this.showslots() : <p>No slots</p>}
      </div>


      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default DatePicker;
```

Answer (score 0):

@water-man , can you test the following code:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import data from './data.js';

class DatePicker extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      counter: 0,
      data: data
    };
    this.showslots = this.showslots.bind(this);
  }

  increment() {
    if (this.state.counter < 6) {
      this.setState(prevState => ({counter: prevState.counter + 1}))
    }
  }

  decrement() {
    if (this.state.counter > 0) {
      this.setState(prevState => ({counter: prevState.counter - 1}))
    }
  }

  showslots() {
    const counter = this.state.counter;
    if (this.state.data.available_slots[counter].date_slots.length === 0) {
      return (
        <p>No slots</p>
      )
    } else {
      const counter = this.state.counter;
      const data_slots = this.state.data.available_slots[counter].date_slots;
      return (
        data_slots.map(obj => {
          return(
          <div id="slotinfo">
            <p>Hour : {obj.hour}</p>
            <p>Hour slots : {obj.hour_slots[0]}</p>
            <p>Hour slots : {obj.hour_slots[0]}</p>
          </div>
          )
        })
      )
    }

  }

  render() {
    console.log(data);
    return (
      <div>

        <div id="center">
          <div className="title">
            <p>Pick a Date</p>
          </div>
          <div className="increment">
            <button type="button" className="btn btn-success" id="plus" onClick={this.increment.bind(this)}>+</button>
          </div>
          <div className="display">
            <input type="text" id="date" value={data.available_slots[this.state.counter].date}/>
          </div>
          <div className="decrement">
            <button type="button" className="btn btn-danger" id="minus" onClick={this.decrement.bind(this)}>-</button>
          </div>
          <div className="status">
            { data.available_slots[this.state.counter].date_slots.length === 0 ?
              <p>No slots available for today</p> : <p>Slots available for today</p> }
          </div>
          <div className="submit">
            <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary" id="submit" onClick={this.showslots}>Book Slot</button>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default DatePicker;
```

Comment: Thanks Salman but I have solved it. I thing to mention in your answer as you are using `map()` we need to keep each`<p>` inside a new  `<div>` tag.